# how to upload multiple image in node.js using formidable with express

Tags: node.js, upload, formidable

I am trying to upload multiple image using jquery plugin [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

I have got in post request like this, when I upload image:

```
app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
    files = [],
    fields = [];
    form.on('field', function(field, value) {
        console.log("field");
        fields.push([field, value]);
    });
    form.on('file', function(field, file) {
        console.log(file.name);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(field));
        files.push([field, file]);
    });
    form.on('end', function() {
         console.log('done');
    });
    form.parse(req);
});
```

Even I could not get console message.

When I upload image, that request contain file like this:

```
files: { files: [ [Object] ] },
```

How to solve this?

Comment: form.on(field) and file and end functions are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to work directly with formidable to do that. The `BodyParser()` from express does what you want (it uses formidable).

Just refere to the doc: [req.files](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files)